# Unsure about state of information after being returned to caller

Tags: c++

I'm new to cpp and am having trouble grasping scope in some places. So when a variable is returned to the caller is it stored inside said calling function. Otherwise, will it just disappear into the ether when not giving parameters for it?

Hope it's clear what I'm asking about.

Comment: Are you referring to the difference between `x = foo();` and just `foo();` when given a function foo that returns an int?

Comment: Yeah sure what would happen with the second one where the function runs but returns an int to no parameters

Comment: Please provide example code in your question (by [edit]ing it) There's a difference between the function returning an `int` vs an `int*`

Comment: The return value of a function is stored in the function's stack and is copied to the caller (in the example above the return is copied to x). So if its not copied, when the function returns, the value is lost along with the function stack. Hope this addresses your doubt.